# A way to download all of the required kde dependencies to start working on kde programming?

Tags: c++, kde4

I've CentOS 6.4 which is running older version of Qt and possibly other such incompatible version components that makes it really difficult to start kde programming on the machine.

Is there a way to download all of the dependencies in one go so that the programming becomes easier?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks people!

Comment: What do you want, install newest KDE on your distro? Or development files for your version?

Comment: I'd like to mod some of the existing applications like kscreenlock etc... to suit my needs.


The problem being that I need to download and install newer qt and a bunch of other such dependencies which are really slowing me down...

Comment: Why do you need newer Qt if you're modifying old kscreenlock, that built with your version? Short answer is you don't. If you want to build new KDE on top of what you already have - that's completely different, of course.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the development packages for packages your system ships with.
2. Find the version of the application you want to play around with.
3. Grab the source for that release from their source control system.
4. Try to compile, install additional missing dependencies you missed in step 1, rinse and repeat until its working.